# ニューロンを模した大量のプロセッサによる非同期処理は、なぜ高速なのか

Tags: 人工知能

「[IBMが人間の脳と同じ構造を持つプロセッサーの開発に成功](http://gigazine.net/news/20140808-ibm-brain-similar-processor-chip/)」という記事に、このようにあります:

> システム全体の作動クロックは1kHzと現代の基準では極めて低いものとなっています
>   ...
>   各コアは非同期的に通信を行い、... TrueNorthの出力密度は1平方センチあたり20mWとなっています。これは、既存のプロセッサであれば1平方センチあたり50Wであることと比較すると文字どおりケタ違いの省電力性能を持っていることになります。

ニューラルネットの非同期化はなぜ、このような高速化が実現されるのですか？

Comment: @HiroshiYamamoto 一応メタに問題提起しました http://meta.ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/1558/

Comment: 質問を具体的にする例を編集で示すと分かりやすいと思いますので、編集してみます。→ ロールバック + 編集しました。「質問の意図を理解するための労力」を減らすために、タイトルを詳細にし、また記事から関係のある箇所をより多く引用するようにしました。

Comment: 対応ありがとうございました。私のコメントは削除いたします。

Comment: @natsukitinyak 質問の大幅な変更はよくない、というメタでの結論に基づいて、最後の変更をロールバックしました。もし思うところありましたら (反対意見など) メタやチャットで教えてください。

Comment: うまく編集しきれなかったので助かりました。ありがとうございます。これで、通報(クローズ)がきた場合は、その時はその時だと思いますので、スタックオーバーフロー‌​‌​のガイドラインから外れていると判断して削除してもらって構いません。（質問にすでに回答がある場合、質問は自身では削除できず、多数決や他の方の意見が必要になるためです。） Hiroshi Yamamotoさんと同じく先ほ‌​どまでのコメントは削除しました。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

その記事の該当箇所は、
「非同期処理が如何にエネルギー効率の良さ(=省電力性能)に寄与しているか」を説明しているのであって、
「非同期処理が高速である」ということを説明しているものではありません。

一般に人間の脳(=ニューラルネット)の高速さ(処理能力の高さ)は、
非同期ではなくニューロンの超並列性によるものとされています。
その記事においても4096コアということですから、
超並列処理こそが高速さを生み出す源泉だと推測されます。

なおプログラミングにおける非同期は、I/Oの速度がCPUよりもかなり遅い、
すなわちCPUがI/Oを待つ時間をうまく別の計算に利用できるようにする仕組みです。
単純な高速化ではなく、処理効率を高めた結果として高速化する、
そういう手段の1つと考えられるでしょう。

Comment: このようにあとから質問を変えられてしまって、回答を修正しろというのは非常に困りますね。

Comment: なお、変更後の質問の回答としては最終段落が該当します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。よりよい質問になりました。